# Magento 1.9 : Cookie restriction mode not working

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie

I activated the cookie restriction mode in the backend & cleared all caches.

The CMS static block called "**cookie_restriction_notice**" is activated too.

But there is no overlay showing up.

I also wasn't able to find any other configuration options.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to show a Cookie restriction notice ("this website uses cookies.. accept") for every visitor who enters the website and therefore activated the cookie restriction mode in the backend.  At least that's how it's explained in the official magento user guide. But can't get it to work.

Comment: If its not working then use https://marketplace.magento.com/hellobrave-cookiecompliance.html

Comment: Also if you want to use it with magento default one then follow these steps: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/cookie-restriction-mode.html

Comment: Check your xml files, you may be removing this from the site?

Comment: I found this in my page.xml
`<block type="page/html_cookieNotice" name="global_cookie_notice" as ="global_cookie_notice" template="page/html/cookienotice.phtml" before="-" />`
It's in line 158 in the "Page Bottom" Section

Comment: @SukumarGorai I already followed the Magento User Guide
and the extension is for M2 so unfortunately this doesn't work for me.
I found a few extensions for M1 too though, but would prefer to get this working with the magento default.

Comment: Try this one for magento 1 https://magecomp.com/free-magento-extensions/magento-cookie-compliance.html